# javascript String() method issues or sort() method?

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

I'm running into some issues with the javscript String() method.Consider the following example.

```
var myArray = [10,1,5,15];
myArray.sort();
console.log(myArray) //Logs 0,1,10,15,5 to the console
```

Is this an issue with the sort() method? Or is the string value of 10 and 15 actually less than the string value of 5?

Comment: Yes, `sort` does stringify the items and compare them lexically by default.

Comment: you can always use a number-sorting function as an argument to sort if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sort is only sorting alphabetically. 
Below is alternative way of sorting

```
function sortNum(firstelement,secoundelement) {
    return firstelement - secoundelement;
}

var numArray = [10,1,5,15];
numArray.sort(sortNum);
```